# Создание списка через узел children

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

В цикле за каждый проход должен создаваться 1 новый элемент списка - li, чтобы по итогу было 10 пунктов списка. Однако выдаёт только 1 пункт. Как исправить?

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');

let ul = document.createElement('ul');

let li = document.createElement('li');

out.appendChild(ul);

for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  ul.appendChild(li);
  ul.children[i] = li;
}
console.log(ul.children.length);
```

```css
ul {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 12px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: строка `ul.children[i] = li;` не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');

let ul = document.createElement('ul');



out.appendChild(ul);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  ul.appendChild(li);
  ul.children[i] = li;
}
console.log(ul.children.length);
```

```css
ul {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 12px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: Чем приведенный код отличается от кода в вопросе? В чем была проблема? Как именно она решилась?